# Journey builder decision split behavior

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, split

We have a simple journey. As soon as a contact enters the journey, a choice is made through the decision split (based on journey data). There are 2 options in the split. An email is sent with each choice. Colleagues did not always get the correct result when testing. Sometimes they received the first email while the data they submitted belonged to the second email.

We have been in contact with Salesforce regarding the decision split. According to the person who handled our case, the decision split works as follows: the decision split looks in the DE to see whether the emailaddress already exists. As soon as he comes across the emailaddress he will use those values. This can therefore produce incorrect results. When we tested it ourselves via Postman, this explanation does not seem to be correct. When I make two different API calls within a few seconds, one for mail 1 and one for mail 2, I receive both emails. This does not seem to match Salesforce's explanation. What could be the reason why my colleagues sometimes do not receive the correct outcome? I read other articles here on Stack Exchange but most of them are based on Contact data.
[image]

Comment: Can you share how you configured your decision split (image)?

Comment: I upload the image.